# Return result from eloquent's saveMany in addition to parent data

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, lumen

After I save data into the database with `Eloquent`'s method `saveMany` - I want to return both `parent data` and `child data` in one `JSON` chunk. The problem is that in my current implementation, I can return either one or another, but not both. What would be the most appropriate and clean way to do it?

I have 2 models:

- `Theader` (i.e. Header)
- `Line`

Relationship is one to many:

```
final class Theader extends Model 
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = array('total_amount', 'name', 'description');

    public function lines()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Line', 'header_id');
    }
}

final class Line extends Model 
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = array('amount', 'description');

    public function theader()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Theader', 'header_id');
    }
}
```

When I insert the new data::

- 1 line goes to `theaders` table. Unique `id` is generated.
- 2 to 100 lines are going to `lines` table. All have the same `header_id`.

Here is the working solution that I have come up with:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Theader;
use App\Line;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TheaderController extends Controller
{   
    public function create(Request $request){
        $input = $request->all();
        $input['name'] = 'My name';
        $input['description'] = 'My description';
        $input['lines'][] = [ 'name' => 'Test 1', 'amount' => 19 ];
        $input['lines'][] = [ 'name' => 'Test 2', 'amount' => 15 ];

        // first create Header
        $header = Theader::create($input);

        // now let's create lines
        $lines = [new Line($input['lines'][0]), new Line($input['lines'][1])];
        $header->lines()->saveMany($lines);

        return response()->json($header);
    }
}
```

In this example - how do I return header + all newly inserted lines in one go?

I can either use `return response()->json($header);` or `return response()->json($header)->lines;` but neither of these options return both `header` and `lines` at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to reload the `lines` relationship after you have saved the data.

This should work for you:

```
// save your lines to your header
$header->lines()->saveMany($lines);

// load/reload the related lines on the $header object
$header->load('lines');

return response()->json($header);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return both lines like this

```
return response()->json(compact('headers', 'lines'));
```

To have everything inside a single object

```
$headers->lines = $lines;
$headers->moreStuff = $moreStuff;
return response()->json($headers);
```

Comment: this workaround indeed works! but in that case lines are not the part of the 'header' array, but rather a separate entity.Another issue is that there might have been additional columns inserted, such as 'created_at' or columns with default values. I want to see all of that newly inserted data. So maybe It will just be easier to make another query for lines..

Comment: You are right. Check my updates and see if it helps you.